# Hive CLI Column delimiter

Tags: hive, hiveql

Hi I'm new to hive and would definitely appreciate some tips.

I'm trying to export hive query results as a csv, in the cli.

I can export them as text using:

hive -e 'set hive.cli.print.header=true; SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME LIMIT 0;' > /file_path/file_name.txt

Can anyone suggest what I need to add in order to get the columns delimited by ','

Comment: any particular reason you want to do it from cli ? I mean how about hive -f ?

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do it directly from hive, instead of going through sed route.

```
SET hive.exec.compress.output=FALSE;
SET hive.cli.print.header=TRUE;
INSERT overwrite local directory '/file_path/file_name.txt' row format delimited fields terminated by ',' SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Hi Sayan, thank you for getting back to me about this.  When I try running your suggestion in hive in the CLI, it exports a text file delimited by ',' but without the column headers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `concat_ws()` function in your query like this

For SELECT *

```
select concat_ws(',',*) from <table-name>;
```

Or if you want particluar columns

```
select concat_ws(',', col_1, col_2, col_3...) from <table-name>;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
hive -e 'set hive.cli.print.header=true; SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME LIMIT 0;' > /file_path/file_name.txt  && cat /file_path/file_name.txt  | sed -e 's/\s/,/g' > /file_path/file_name.formatted.txt
```

once your query creates the output file, then use sed to replace the space with "," as show above.

Comment: Hi Ramisetty, thank you for getting back to me about this.  When I try running your suggestion in CLI I get a text file with the headers and columns delimited by ',' but some of the values in some of the rows don't line up with the Column headers.

Comment: can u please elaborate what line up you mean ?

Comment: This won't work if you have spaces in any of your data